# Printing on small sheets of polypropylene

Tags: print-design, print-production, screen-printing

I'm looking to print on sheets of Polypropylene (PP) (the size of a playing card). It would be to put custom designs on PP sleeves, that look like this:

[image]

I've considered some options, like screen printing them but that would be very tedious work I think (no exp with it tho and cost more then it should?). Per design I make I'd have to probably print on about 60 ~ 200 of these.

If more information is needed please ask! Any advice is welcome!

Comment: Probably more information is needed. Is that the base color? Do they come in white? Designs like a photo? or just a logo.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the artwork to be printed is just simple basic line art, and assuming you just need a one color print, screen printing may be your best option. For arguments sake let's use the number 100 as the amount of sheets you need printed. Screen print pricing varies from state to state. I happen to live in the screen-printing and embroidery capital of the world (New Jersey) so my pricing may be a bit less expensive on average but these following numbers may help you make a decision.

1. **$1.10** per piece for the screen-printing (as a one color print).
2. **$.50** per piece for the additive that needs to be added to the ink so it will adhere to the polypropylene
3. **$25** one time screen/set up charge

**TOTAL = $185**

That should be a good guesstimate as to a general cost

---

As far as screen-printing is concerned, that job would be simple and should take no longer than two hours to make the screen, set up on press, and print the job.

Comment: Holy **** that's a lot of costs.. and completely not cost efficient.. I see competitors do this and sell - let's say - 60 of these sleeves for around $30.. :/

Comment: If you were getting 500 of them printed you would probably only pay $.30 per piece.. That's generally how it goes the more you get printed, the cheaper the cost

Comment: I was actually considering a Desktop sized Inkjet flatbed printer using a jig for the sleeves. think this could be a cheaper and more solid solution?